# Is there a way to run a saved SQL query from Python (using cx_Oracle)?

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I have been using `cx_Oracle` to perform SQL queries on an Oracle database in Python. So far I have been pasting these queries into strings and then running them using the `cursor.execute()` function that comes with cx_Oracle:

```
#simple example
query = """SELECT *
           FROM my_table"""
cursor.execute(query)
```

However, my select queries have gotten quite complex, and the code is starting to look a bit messy. I was wondering if there were any way to simply save the SQL code into a .sql file and for Python or cx_Oracle to call that file? I thought something like that might be simple to find using Google, but my searches are oddly coming up dry.

Comment: `.sql` files are just text files, and SQL queries in Python are just strings, so there is nothing stopping you from reading queries from a separate file in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can certainly save SQL code to a file and load it:

```
query = open('foo.sql', 'r').read()
cursor.execute(query)
```

I can't find any reference to saved queries in cx_Oracle, so that may be your best bet.

Comment: This is indeed all I was looking for. I presumed there was some simple solution I was overlooking. For reference, I am using the following code:
with open(file_name.sql) as f: 
    query = f.read()
cursor.execute(query) since the with will properly handle exceptions and also close the file.